# Trans/Cis Alkene with mCPBA products?

Tags: organic-chemistry

What is the different in stereochemistry between the product of cis alkene with mCPBA and trans alkene with mCPBA, I drew the products, they do look different but the configurations are the exact same, does that mean that they give the same products?

[image]

Comment: The configurations of the products of the trans alkene are wrong!

Comment: can you please elaborate why?

Comment: The first is RR (not RS) and the second is SS (not SR). Remember the CIP rules. You should look at each carbon atom in such a way that the hydrogen atom points backwards.

Comment: Sorry Im not following, in the first molecule, the carbon on right has already hydrogen going inside, the O has the highest priority and it goes counterclockwise to the carbon on the left (priority 2)

Comment: See this diagram: https://imgur.com/a/38EkRS5

Comment: In your diagram, why cant i just draw an arrow from 1 to 3 counterclock wise?

Comment: Because oxygen is in pointing outwards the screen. An arrow from 1 to 3 (passing through 2) is clockwise.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120427/discussion-between-sharbel-damouni-and-lemoine).